# How to locate the object in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click a icon in between 2 icon because both are having same class name though its having two different xpath but xpath does not content handler so findElement(By.xpath()) comment is not working. Below is the difference in HTML

```
class="doughnut-clicker-circle" questiontype="hypothetical" 

class="doughnut-clicker-circle" questiontype="multichoice"
```

Only difference is questiontype. Can someone tell me how find the element in selenium + Java.

```
<svg>
<circle class="doughnut-clicker-circle" questiontype="multichoice" learningobjid="dfe00abe-cef8-11e3-8be9-67ee60a9f4aa" learningobjname="Determine whether trespassers have a right to capture property." data-action="/assessmentRetrievalService/getQuestionForStudyCenterLearn" data-handler="loadStudyCenter" fill="transparent" r="48" cy="53" cx="53">
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

<svg>
<circle class="doughnut-clicker-circle" questiontype="hypothetical" learningobjid="dfe00abe-cef8-11e3-8be9-67ee60a9f4aa" learningobjname="Determine whether trespassers have a right to capture property." data-action="/assessmentRetrievalService/getQuestionForStudyCenterLearn" data-handler="loadStudyCenter" fill="transparent" r="48" cy="53" cx="53">
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find these elements using combination of identifiers. Let's say by class and by attribute value, for example `//*[@class='doughnut-clicker-circle' and @questiontype='hypothetical']` and `//*[@class='doughnut-clicker-circle' and @questiontype='multichoice']`.

Comment: Able to launch Hypo question but not able to lunch Multiple choice using same code.
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='doughnut-clicker-circle' and @questiontype='multichoice']")).click();

Comment: Are you sure that element "Multiple" is not changed after you click "Hypo" element?

Comment: I am running two different test cases for multiple choice and hypo. so when I enter driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='doughnut-clicker-circle' and @questiontype='multichoice']")).click(); its not able find the element.

Comment: And what if you run test related to 'hypo' as the first one? Is this element located?

Answer (score 0):

Will post a Java code since I worked with Selenium under Java (hope this helps in your case):

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "circle[questiontype*='multichoice']")
private WebElement circle;
```

Basically, you need to find an element after the following CSS:

`"circle[questiontype*='multichoice']"`

Meaning the `circle` tag having the attribute `questiontype` with the value `multichoice` (the value must contain the string `multichoice` not be equal to it).